# Disable swagger in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am new to Swagger and have implemented Swagger UI with spring mvc, I want to disable UI on production/live environment. I am struggling to figure it out.

This is what I am using

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {


}
```

RestController.java

```
    @RestController
    @Api(value="city", description="Operations pertaining to City Data")
    @RequestMapping(value="/v1/city")
    public class RestController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "View city by stateId or stateName")
        @RequestMapping(value="/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getCityBystateId(@RequestBody StateDto stateDto,Model model){
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove it or only to set as unreachable from outside calls ?

Comment: Yes that was whole idea,  I didn't want to expose my end points to public on production.

Comment: Then you can use a reserve-proxy and filtered access according patterns, no ?

Comment: Bingo that's what I have done,  blocked the url from HAProxy

Comment: OK, I'll add a response according that, In my environment I use also a reverse-proxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to use a reverse proxy to reject access to Swagger Api on your production environment.

In this case your production installation is exactly the same as your development/test environment (then more compliant with DevOps method) and you can continue to access your Swagger API with internal calls.

Comment: I have also used the same approach, I have blocked the url on HAProxy :D

Answer (score 7):

Look into the Spring's [profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles) mechanism that lets you register different beans in different environments

When you bootstrap it according to doc, you can annotate your swagger config class on a class level with e.g. `@Profile("dev")`, thus enabling the swagger configuration for the environment of your choice

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("dev")
public class SwaggerConfig {


}
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. Be aware that it works on some types of beans (@Configuration here works and is the best practise) but I have seen it other places where it is used on @Controller and it doesn't work there.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. First I assumed `@EnableSwagger2` must be listed in the "SpringBoot class" (with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and stuff) but your code showed me that I can annotate my own `ApiDocumentationConfiguration` too. Thanks!

Comment: /swagger-ui.html still available but there is no methods. Is there way to forbid URL ?